# After installing tf-nightly-gpu i now receive these warnings below. How do i get rid of them?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.base. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint_management. The old module will be deleted in version 2.9.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.resource has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.resource. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.util has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base_delegate has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.base_delegate. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.graph_view has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.graph_view. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.python_state has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.python_state. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.saving.functional_saver has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.functional_saver. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.saving.checkpoint_options has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint_options. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @muma, please try installing the stable version of tensorflow and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.